# How to remove all whitespace between a two characters?

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I'm trying to correct some issues caused by badly copied files. One issue is that due to some kind of auto formatting I have code that used to look like this:

```
ViewBag.MenuImage = "image-name"
```

Has become this:

```
ViewBag.MenuImage = " image - name "
```

In order to save hours of merging, I decided to use regex, it's been helpful for most things but I can't work out how to correct this using RegEx.

Using simply `\s` does match all the characters and I can do something like `ViewBag\.MenuImage\s*?=\s*?"(.*)"` to capture the group of what I want to change. The issue is that I need to do this in a single operation, as I am using find and replace in Visual Studio.

Is there some way of combining these two regex into a single one so I can simply replace it with blank?

Comment: Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a .NET regex engine you may use

```
(?<=ViewBag\.MenuImage\s*=\s*"[^"]*?)\s+
```

Replace with an empty string. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DViewBag%5C.MenuImage%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%3F%29%5Cs%2B&i=ViewBag.MenuImage%20%3D%20%22%20image%20-%20name%20%22&r=).

**Details**

- `(?<=ViewBag\.MenuImage\s*=\s*"[^"]*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with

  - `ViewBag\.MenuImage` - a `ViewBag.MenuImage` string
  - `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `"` - a `"` char
  - `[^"]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `"`, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces.